# sns.kdeplot - Y-axis of the plot is undesirable

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to plot a distribution graph in Python using sns.kdeplot. 
You can use x = np.random(size=100) to generate a sample data, but my actual data has completely different values (I don't have normal dist data).

I want to plot the weight or percentage that each value is among the total number of values. For example, if I have 100 data, and there're 10 0.5's. Then my desirable result is that 0.5 takes 10% of the total population, so the y-axis when x=0.5 should be 10%(0.1).

[see plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtudv.png) (I'm not sure why the axis is not shown, x-axis range from 0-1, and y-axis range from 0-1.4 in the graph)
The result graph is not what I want. The range of y-axis is (0,1.4). However, I want every points added to be 1, which means none of the values should be greater than 1. 
Can someone help? Am I using the wrong plot package?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
sns.kdeplot(All['variable'].astype('float'), shade=True, label='variable 
distribution')
```

Comment: Just to make sure I am tracking the question correctly: you have some collection of 1 dimensional data (like a list) and you would like a histogram that shows the frequency of values in that list (probably binned in some way) normalized by the number of elements in the list? Seaborn's distplot is pretty flexible! https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see the picture I uploaded. I tried sns.distplot, but the result is the same. Yes you understand me correctly, except I don't want any normalization. I just want to show the frequency of values in that list. The code actually works for most of my data, but just not for this parameter, where each values are from 0-1. The picture I uploaded shouldn't have y-axis of 1.4